# NetworkOnMainThreadException after changing target sdkVersion

Tags: android, exception

How do I should this exception?

After I changed my target sdkVersion to 13. this issue occurs! 
What went wrong?

This is the logcat output after I tried to load my advertisement

```
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:164)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at com.sfa.coverflow.ImageLoader.DisplayAdvert(ImageLoader.java:93)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at com.sfa.coverflow.MainActivity$LoadAdvert.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:869)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at com.sfa.coverflow.MainActivity$LoadAdvert.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4446)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-04 12:51:23.910: E/AndroidRuntime(7379):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my DisplayAdvert method:

```
int advert_id = R.drawable.loader; 
public void DisplayAdvert(String image_url, int loader, ImageView image) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    advert_id = loader;
    imageViews.put(image, image_url);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(image_url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        if(myBitmap!=null)
        image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(image_url, image);
            image.setImageResource(loader);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is my LoadAdvert method:

```
/**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAdvert extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_advertisement, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Advert: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // ADVERT FOUND
                    // RETRIEVE ADVENT URL
                    advert = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PHOTOS);

                    for (int i = 0; i < advert.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = advert.getJSONObject(i);

                        // STORE EACH JSON ITEM IN VARIABLE
                        banner_url = c.getString(TAG_BANNER_IMAGE);
                        banner_url = banner_url.toString();
                        Log.d("banner URL", banner_url);

                        advert_url = c.getString(TAG_ADVERT_URL);
                        advert_url = advert_url.toString();
                        Log.d("advert URL", advert_url);
                    }       
                } 
                else {

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

                    // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
                    int loader = R.drawable.loader;

                    // Imageview to show
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_advert);

                    // Image url
                    String imageUrl = banner_url;

                    // ImageLoader class instance
                    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

                    // whenever you want to load an image from url
                    // call DisplayImage function
                    // url - image url to load
                    // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
                    // image - ImageView 
                    imgLoader.DisplayAdvert(imageUrl, loader, image);           

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are targeting Honeycomb sdk or higher, then you can't perform network operation on main thread. You must have to run all the network related task in background for that you can use AsyncTask.

Comment: `imgLoader.DisplayAdvert(imageUrl, loader, image);`   line causing problem just move network related code inside background

Comment: Hi, you mean I have to create an async task in my imgLoader class?

Answer (score 2):

This part of the stack trace is the "killer";

```
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:164)
at com.sfa.coverflow.ImageLoader.DisplayAdvert(ImageLoader.java:93)
at com.sfa.coverflow.MainActivity$LoadAdvert.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:869)
```

Your `onPostExecute` which is executed on the GUI thread *when the AsyncTask is complete* calls `DisplayAdvert` that promptly calls `HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect`. Since network access is not allowed on the GUI thread in newer API versions, this throws the Exception.

The network access inside `DisplayAdvert` needs to be done in a non GUI thread instead since it performs network I/O.

The easiest way to do that is to create a new AsyncTask in your `DisplayAdvert` method, do the network access in `doInBackground()`, and update the GUI with the fetched data in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to test your code then you can add following code  to this to your `onCreate()`

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { 
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        }
```

You don't want this to be permanent, as network operations on the UI thread makes for a bad experience when using the app, but can be useful when testing.

Answer (score 0):

Put your DisplayAdvert method in doInBackground, as you can not perform network operations on main thread from api level 11 and above

see this [Resource](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to perform network operations in the main thread.

In the code posted by you, you are perfoming network operation in `display()` and are calling it in the `onPost()` of an `AsycTask`.

In `AsyncTask` only the `doInBackground()` is performed in another thread, the method `onPost()` is executed in the main thread itself.

Please feel free to ask any further doubts.

Comment: So does it mean that I place my displayAdvert method in doInBackground of my imgLoader class?

Comment: @user1933630 Yes either you should do that or you should create a second AsyncTask and execute it from the onPost of the first, else you can call the display() in another thread, as you wish

Answer (score 0):

The apps targeting to Honeycomb will get this exception, network operations should not be allowed in main UI thread.

Your have to do all network operations in a separate thread(Multithreading) or use AsyncTask.

**Updated:**

```
 public void DisplayAdvert(final String image_url, final int loader, final ImageView image) 
    {
        advert_id = loader;
        imageViews.put(image, image_url);
        try 
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                Bitmap myBitmap;
                public void run() 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        URL url = new URL(image_url);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            if(myBitmap!=null)
                                image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                            else
                            {
                                queuePhoto(image_url, image);
                                image.setImageResource(loader);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();
       }
       catch (Exception e) 
       {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Comment: I am trying this piece of code but it says that there is a syntax error at "   runOnUIThread()
    {
        public void run()
        {"

Comment: It also says "cannot refer to a non-final variable image_url in an inner clas....." how do i solve it